# do something if (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

i have made this:

```
$case=mysql_query("select * from project where url='$url'");


while($result=mysql_fetch_array($case))

{

$one = $result['date'];
$two = $result['time'];

}
```

`$one` contain the date of my article and `$two` contain the time of my article.

I need to do:

if `$uno` and `$two` is > of all row in my database called `project` do something.

Is possibile?

Update:

mysql information:

Date is "DATE" type and Time is "VARCHAR" type.

output example: 2016-02-10 - 12:22:18

Comment: mysql_? This has been deprecated for a looooooong time now. Please move to mysqli_ or PDO. Secondly, it is impossible to find values that are greater than all the values your are fetching. Finding the largest is possible however.

Comment: Please provide a list of example data you have in your table, and give the data type of "date" and "time".

Comment: i have update my question

Comment: Do you **only** need the largest values, or do you still need all the other rows in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL instead:

```sql
select    `date`, `time`
from      project
where     url='$url'
order by  1 desc, 2 desc;
```

Then the **first** record you get will also represent the most recent date/time combination.

If you are not interested in the other records, then add `limit 1` to the SQL, and you will then only get one result:

```sql
select    `date`, `time`
from      project
where     url='$url'
order by  1 desc, 2 desc
limit     1;
```